# Differentiability of a piecewise function confusion about wording

Tags: calculus, derivatives, continuity

So I have this question here.

[image]

Some background. I already took calculus(Single/Multivariable) along with many other math courses so I would know how to do this questions fairly easily. The constraints in this question is what's tripping me up.

For part $i)$, $m=\frac{5}{8}$ and $b=\frac{3}{2}$.

I'm not really sure what part $ii)$ is asking to be fair. I can't use the rules of differentiation so i'm stuck with using first principles, (i.e. the definition).

If I attempt to use the definition that they give me, then:

$f_{-}'(4)=\displaystyle{\lim_{x \to 0}} \frac{f(4+h)-f(4)}{h}$

and

$f_{+}'(4)=\displaystyle{\lim_{h \to 0}} \frac{f(4+h)-f(4)}{h}$

But now like, what to I substitute in? My intuition is telling me for the first limit, I would sub in the $\frac{2}{x+2}$ to get:

$f_{-}'(4)=\displaystyle{\lim_{h \to 0}} \frac{\frac{2}{x+h+2}-\frac{4}{4+2}}{h}$

However, if I attempt to do that for the other limit, I can't evaluate the $f(4)$ term since the limit from the right is undefined.

My second ideas was to use the function in the middle, namely:

$f_{+}'(4)=\displaystyle{\lim_{h \to 0}} \frac{(\frac{5}{8}(x+h)+\frac{3}{2})-(\frac{5}{8}(x)+\frac{3}{2})}{h}$

$f_{+}'(4)=\displaystyle{\lim_{h \to 0}} \frac{(\frac{5}{8}(4+h)+\frac{3}{2})-(\frac{5}{8}(4)+\frac{3}{2})}{h}$

and then proceed but then, I'm not really sure if this technique i'm using is even right. Can someone nudge me in the right direction? Thanks!

Comment: It's the limit at 4 not around negative 4. 2/(x+2) is for x <-4 which is nowhere close to 4.

Comment: OHH. I see. The wording totally tripped me up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that your function for $x>4$ is actually $$\frac {x-4}{\sqrt x -2} =  \frac {(\sqrt x-2)(\sqrt x+2)}{\sqrt x-2}= \sqrt x+2$$
That should make your computations straight forward.

Comment: No I get that, but what do I plug in for the limit itself? Would it just be:

$f_{+}'(4)=\displaystyle{\lim_{h \to 0}} \frac{\frac{4+h-4}{\sqrt{4+h}-2}-(\sqrt{4}+2)}{h}=\frac{5}{8}x+\frac{3}{2}$

$f_{+}'(4)=\displaystyle{\lim_{h \to 0}} \frac{\frac{4+h-4}{\sqrt{4+h}-2}-(\sqrt{4}+2)}{h}=\frac{5}{8}(4)+\frac{3}{2}$

And then would I just check that both sides equaled each other?

Comment: $ f'_+(4) = \lim _{x\to 4} \frac {(\sqrt x +2) -4}{x-4} =1/4 $

Comment: Yeah I got it. I just needed to clear things up :) .

Comment: Thanks for  your attention and understanding.